# Solving Hashi in graph theory

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Today's (April 3, 2022) *New York Times magazine* has a new class of puzzle, ***HASHI***, by Prasanna Seshadri:  "Connect the islands (the circles with numbers) with as many bridges as specified by the number on the island.  No more than two bridges can connect adjoining islands.  Bridges cannot cross islands or other bridges.  When you're done, the islands must all be interconnected."

**Example**:

[image: Hashi puzzle]

Which has solution:

[image: Hashi solution]

[generating code, below]

Although the statement doesn't refer to mathematics explicitly, this is clearly a problem in graph theory.  We are to form a *connected*, *undirected*, *planar* graph through the placed vertices with stated vertex orders, with the constraint that no two vertices can be joined by more than two edges.

I would like code that will take as input a list of vertices with `VertexCoordinates` and `VertexDegree` and produce a planar graph solution (there may be more than one solution).

Although I can envision an approach generating a large number of graphs with the placed vertices, then selecting those that have the proper vertex orders, and then selecting for planarity, I strongly suspect that approach is so computationally costly as to be irrelevant to the full puzzles in the magazine, which this week contains 28 vertices.

The precise form of input isn't crucial, though the following would certainly work:

```
 {{label1,{xcoord1,ycoord1},degree1},
 {label2,{xcoord2,ycoord2},degree2},
...
 }
```

where for the above problem:

```
data = {
    {a, {0,1}, 3},
    {b, {1,1}, 2},
    {c, {1/3,2/3}, 1},
    {d, {2/3,2/3}, 2},
    {e, {1,1/3}, 1},
    {f, {0,0}, 4},
    {g, {2/3,0}, 3}}
```

**Addendum**:  Although the complete instructions (above) do not state it, I'm sure (now) that edges must be vertical or horizontal.  The Wikipedia page on Hashi specifies this constraint; it seems to eliminate the multiplicity of solutions.  Moreover, now given two weeks of solutions through the *New York Times*, it is clear that only vertical and horizontal "bridges" are allowed.

---

Code for the above:

```
Graph[
 {Labeled[a, Placed[Text[Style["3", Bold, 24]], Center]],
  Labeled[b, Placed[Text[Style["2", Bold, 24]], Center]],
  Labeled[c, Placed[Text[Style["1", Bold, 24]], Center]],
  Labeled[d, Placed[Text[Style["2", Bold, 24]], Center]],
  Labeled[e, Placed[Text[Style["1", Bold, 24]], Center]],
  Labeled[f, Placed[Text[Style["4", Bold, 24]], Center]],
  Labeled[g, Placed[Text[Style["3", Bold, 24]], Center]]},
 {a \[UndirectedEdge] b, a \[UndirectedEdge] f, 
  a \[UndirectedEdge] f, b \[UndirectedEdge] e, 
  c \[UndirectedEdge] d, d \[UndirectedEdge] g, 
  f \[UndirectedEdge] g, f \[UndirectedEdge] g},
 VertexCoordinates -> 
    {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1/3, 2/3}, {2/3, 2/3}, 
     {1, 1/3}, {0, 0}, {2/3, 0}},
VertexShape -> Graphics[{Red,Circle[]}],
VertexSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Do you suppose the answer is unique, or are there many possible solutions for a given puzzle?

Comment: The *Times* puzzle department (edited by Will Shortz) is usually quite good about such matters, so I strongly expect there is a unique solution.

Comment: they may be multiple answers: if you replace the list of edges in your example with `{a <-> b, a <-> f, a <-> d, b <-> e, c <-> f, d <-> g, f <-> g,  f <-> g}` you get another answer.

Comment: `{a <-> d, a <-> f, a <-> f, b <-> e, c <-> d, b <-> g, f <-> g,  f <-> g}` gives yet another.

Comment: if the bridges can only go north-south or east-west  the cases like the two above are ruled out.

Comment: Thanks... very helpful.  Given the full 28-vertex problem in the *Times*, I'm rather certain links can go any orientation.  In fact, I suspect (but don't know) that links need not be straight.  Regardless, code that gets *any* solution would be an accomplishment (and certainly accepted $\checkmark$).

Comment: Very interestinq! are you sure bridges can go in any orientation though? the [hashiwokakero puzzle game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashiwokakero), which the article mentions has been published in the *Times* under the name *Hashi* (and which you can also play [here!](https://www.puzzle-bridges.com/)), is always played on a rectangular grid. Unless the *Times* is doing a variation on it this time? either way, both questions are interesting! :)

Comment: @thorimur:  I copied all the puzzle instructions verbatim, so you know as much as I do!

Comment: There are multiple answers, given the instructions as stated. Therefore, the instructions need to be clarified. (1) The first week's NYT Hashi has for its "Ex." [example], as well as its published answer, "Hashi" diagrams with all bridges at right angles. Does this condition need to be added to the instructions? (2) Rereading the instructions, are they using a funny definition of "interconnected"? (I was thinking maybe connected along a single uninterrupted path, but that's not it.) SOMETHING'S WRONG, PROBABLY WITH THE INSTRUCTIONS. As I and others have found, there are too many possible solut

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solving this question was quite challenging before I search journals and found out it's an **NP-Complete** ([Source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S002001900900235X)) and surprising it's has [three answers in Code Golf Community](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/hashiwokakero-build-bridges) (people compete usually on fewer lines-of-code solutions).

My first few attempts were using iterative approaches, simplifying the graph and solving it gradually. For example, if there is a 1-1 edge, then if you haven't a 2-node graph, it would never be connected to each other and similarly, nodes with capacity 8 should have 2 bridges on each side.

But soon or later you will reach a point in which you have nothing to simplify based on their capacity and/or number of edges. Sometimes you have to remove edges because it's obvious that edge will make the graph not connected (or inter-connected ;) or more specifically `WeaklyConnectedGraphQ`) that's where it becomes hard.

This solution will first simplify the graph (optional), then uses [Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization)'s constraint solver to find possible trees that cover all the vertices and satisfy the vertex capacity, then we check whether a combination is good or search for another.

Why Google OR-Tools when Mathematica has an entire guide page on optimization, well because in this particular case I couldn't use `FindInstance` as efficiently as OR-Tools which has a native library and has been used in the production environment.

##### Before we start, we need these 3 java libraries (all of them are from google):

- [ortools-java-3.19.4](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/download/v9.3/ortools-java-9.3.10497.jar)
- [ortools-win32-x86-64-9.3.10497](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/download/v9.3/ortools-win32-x86-64-9.3.10497.jar)
- [protobuf-java-3.19.4](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.19.4/protobuf-java-3.19.4.jar)

#### Loading OR-tools via `JLink` + defining a class

```
<< JLink`;

AddToClassPath["C:\\protobuf-java-3.19.4.jar"];
AddToClassPath["C:\\ortools-win32-x86-64-9.3.10497.jar"];
AddToClassPath["C:\\ortools-java-9.3.10497.jar"];

LoadJavaClass["com.google.ortools.Loader"];
Loader`loadNativeLibraries[]
```

```
Hashiwokakero`Private`findCombination=ExternalEvaluate["Java","
import com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.Solver;
import com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.IntVar;
import com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.DecisionBuilder;


class find_combinations{
    Solver solver;
    IntVar[] edges_to_solve;
    
    public find_combinations(int[][] edges_weight_min_max,int[] vertex_capacity,int[][] connections,int[][] intesections){
    
       
    this.solver =  new Solver(\"test\");
    this.edges_to_solve = new IntVar[edges_weight_min_max.length];
    
    //    add min and max for each edge weight
    for(int i =0;i < edges_weight_min_max.length;i++){
        int min = edges_weight_min_max[i][0];
        int max = edges_weight_min_max[i][1];
        
        if (min==max){
            this.edges_to_solve[i]=this.solver.makeIntConst(min);
        }else{
            this.edges_to_solve[i]=this.solver.makeIntVar(min, max);
        }
    }
    
    //    add vertex capacity constrain
    for(int i =0;i < connections.length;i++){
        
        
        IntVar[] temp;
        if (connections[i][3]!=0){
            temp=new IntVar[4];
        }else if (connections[i][2]!=0){
            temp=new IntVar[3];
        }else if (connections[i][1]!=0){
            temp=new IntVar[2];
        }else{
            temp=new IntVar[1];
        }
        
        for(int j =0;j < 4;j++){
            if (connections[i][j]==0){
                break;
            }
            temp[j]=this.edges_to_solve[connections[i][j]-1];
            
        }
        
        this.solver.addConstraint(this.solver.makeSumEquality(temp, vertex_capacity[i]));
    }

    //  add intersection constrain
    for(int i =0;i < intesections.length;i++){
        if (intesections[i].length == 2){
            this.solver.addConstraint(this.solver.makeEquality(this.solver.makeIntConst(0),this.solver.makeProd(this.edges_to_solve[intesections[i][0]-1],this.edges_to_solve[intesections[i][1]-1])));
        }
    }
    
    DecisionBuilder db =
        this.solver.makePhase(this.edges_to_solve, this.solver.INT_VAR_SIMPLE, this.solver.INT_VALUE_SIMPLE);

    this.solver.newSearch(db);
    
  }
    
   public long[] get(){
       
       if (this.solver.nextSolution()){
            long[] result= new long[this.edges_to_solve.length];

            for(int i =0;i < this.edges_to_solve.length;i++){
                result[i]=this.edges_to_solve[i].value();
            }
       
           return result;
       }
       
       this.solver.endSearch();
       return new long[0];
   }
   
   public void stop(){
       this.solver.endSearch();
   }
    
}

"];
```

---

#### Defining `` Hashiwokakero`simplify ``, `` Hashiwokakero`buildGraph `` and `` Hashiwokakero`solve ``

```
BeginPackage["Hashiwokakero`", {"JLink`"}];
ClearAll[simplify,buildGraph,solve];
Begin["`Private`"];
ClearAll[edgeSafeDelete,nodeWeightKIndices,selectIntersections,checkPossibleBridgesOverlaps,buildGraph];

edgeSafeDelete[graph_,{}]:=graph;
edgeSafeDelete[graph_,edges_]:=Block[{temp=Intersection[Join[#,Reverse/@#]&@EdgeList[graph],DeleteDuplicatesBy[edges,Sort]]},If[temp=!={},EdgeDelete[graph,temp],graph]]
nodeWeightKIndices[graph_,k_]:=Catenate@Position[AnnotationValue[graph,VertexWeight],k,{1}];

selectIntersections[{{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_}},listOfVectors_,edges_]:=Block[{data=Flatten[listOfVectors,{2,3}],temp},
temp=Transpose[{Sign[data[[1]]-x1]*Sign[x2-data[[1]]]+Sign[y1-data[[2]]]*Sign[data[[4]]-y1],Sign[x1-data[[1]]]*Sign[data[[3]]-x1]+Sign[data[[2]]-y1]*Sign[y2-data[[2]]]}];
edges[[Catenate@Position[temp,{2,_}|{_,2},{1}]]]
]

checkPossibleBridgesOverlaps[islands_,possibleBridges_]:=Table[
Catenate[Values@GroupBy[possibleBridges[[i]],Switch[islands[[#,2]]-islands[[i,2]],{_?Positive,0},1,{_?Negative,0},3,{0,_?Positive},2,{0,_?Negative},4]&,TakeSmallestBy[EuclideanDistance[islands[[i,2]],islands[[#,2]]]&,1]]],{i,Length@islands}]

buildGraph[coordinatesAndCapacity_]:=Block[{data=Transpose@Prepend[Transpose@coordinatesAndCapacity,Range@Length@coordinatesAndCapacity],data1PB,data1GraphRules,currentGraph},
data1PB=checkPossibleBridgesOverlaps[data,Catenate@Position[data,{_,{Except[#1],#2},_}|{_,{#1,Except[#2]},_},{1}]&@@@data[[All,2]]];
data1GraphRules=Catenate@MapIndexed[Thread[{First@#2,#1}]&,data1PB];
currentGraph=Graph[DeleteDuplicatesBy[data1GraphRules,Sort]
,VertexCoordinates->data[[All,2]]
,VertexLabels->Thread[Range[Length@data]->data[[All,3]]]
,VertexCapacity->data[[All,3]]
,VertexWeight->data[[All,3]]
];

Do[AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edge},"EdgeWeight"]={0,1,2};,{edge,EdgeList[currentGraph]}];

currentGraph
]

checkPossibleBridgesOverlaps[islands_,possibleBridges_]:=Table[
Catenate[Values@GroupBy[possibleBridges[[i]],Switch[islands[[#,2]]-islands[[i,2]],{_?Positive,0},1,{_?Negative,0},3,{0,_?Positive},2,{0,_?Negative},4]&,TakeSmallestBy[EuclideanDistance[islands[[i,2]],islands[[#,2]]]&,1]]],{i,Length@islands}]


simplify[graph_]:=Block[{currentGraph=graph},

(*remove 1-1 bridge - one time*)
Block[{oneNodes=nodeWeightKIndices[currentGraph,1]},
currentGraph=EdgeDelete[currentGraph,EdgeList[currentGraph,(Alternatives@@oneNodes)\[UndirectedEdge](Alternatives@@oneNodes)]];
];

(*cap 2-2 edge weight - one time*)
Block[{oneNodes=nodeWeightKIndices[currentGraph,2]},
Do[AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edge},"EdgeWeight"]={0,1};,{edge,EdgeList[currentGraph,(Alternatives@@oneNodes)\[UndirectedEdge](Alternatives@@oneNodes)]}];
];

(*assing {0,1} to all bridges to/from 1 capacity islands - one time*)
Block[{verticesWithOneCapacityIndex=nodeWeightKIndices[currentGraph,1]},
Do[AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,i},"EdgeWeight"]={0,1};,{i,EdgeList[currentGraph,(Alternatives@@verticesWithOneCapacityIndex)\[UndirectedEdge]_]}];
];

(*find all intersections *)
Block[{edges=EdgeList[currentGraph]
,edgesCoordinates=Partition[Extract[AnnotationValue[currentGraph,VertexCoordinates],List/@Catenate[List@@@EdgeList[currentGraph]]],2]},
Do[AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edges[[i]]},"Intersections"]=selectIntersections[edgesCoordinates[[i]],edgesCoordinates,edges];,{i,Length@edges}];
];

(*filter ceratain edges like a node with capacity 5 and 3 bridges, surely has 3 bridges*)
Do[Block[{vertices=Select[nodeWeightKIndices[currentGraph,k],EdgeCount[currentGraph,#\[UndirectedEdge]_]==Ceiling[k/2]&],evenQ=EvenQ[k],edges},
edges=EdgeList[currentGraph,(Alternatives@@vertices)\[UndirectedEdge]_];

edges=Pick[edges,Length/@AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edges},"EdgeWeight"],2|3];

AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edges},"EdgeWeight"]=If[evenQ,2,Select[#>0&]/@AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edges},"EdgeWeight"]];
currentGraph=edgeSafeDelete[currentGraph,Catenate@AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edges},"Intersections"]];

];,{k,3,8}];

(*update all the intersections*)
Block[{edges=EdgeList[currentGraph]},
Do[AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edge},"Intersections"]=Intersection[AnnotationValue[{currentGraph,edge},"Intersections"],Join[edges,Reverse/@edges]];,{edge,edges}];
];

currentGraph
]

solve[g_]:=Module[{graph=Hashiwokakero`simplify[g],edges,nodesCapacity,connections,intersections,edgesWeightMinMax,counter=1,combination},

edges=EdgeList[graph];

edgesWeightMinMax=MinMax/@AnnotationValue[{graph,edges},"EdgeWeight"];

nodesCapacity=AnnotationValue[graph,VertexCapacity];

connections=Table[Catenate@Position[edges,i\[UndirectedEdge]_|_\[UndirectedEdge]i,{1}],{i,VertexCount[graph]}];

connections=PadRight[connections,{VertexCount[graph],4},0];

intersections=Catenate@Table[Thread@{EdgeIndex[graph,edge],EdgeIndex[graph,#]&/@AnnotationValue[{graph,edge},"Intersections"]},{edge,edges}];
If[intersections=={},intersections={{}}];


intersections=DeleteDuplicatesBy[intersections,Sort];

JavaBlock[Module[{temp},

temp=JavaNew[findCombination,edgesWeightMinMax,nodesCapacity,connections,intersections];
combination=temp@get[];
If[combination==={},Return[{}]];

While[Not@WeaklyConnectedGraphQ@EdgeDelete[graph,Pick[edges,combination,0]],
counter+=1;
combination=temp@get[];
If[combination==={},Return[{}]];
];
temp@stop[];
]];

Print["Found answer in ",counter," iteration."];

EdgeDelete[EdgeAdd[graph,Pick[edges,combination,2]],Pick[edges,combination,0]]
]

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

---

### How does it work?

Input format should be `{{{x1,y1},capacity1}, ..., {{xN,yN},capacityN}}`.

assuming your sample data:

```
data={{{0, 1}, 3}, {{1, 1}, 2}, {{1/3, 2/3}, 1}, {{2/3, 2/3}, 2}
     ,{{1, 1/3}, 1}, {{0, 0}, 4}, {{2/3, 0}, 3}};
```

First, build the graph (it also defines other properties):

```
buildGraph[data]
```

Output:

[image]

Then, apply `solve` to find a solution:

```
solve[buildGraph[data]]

(* Print: "Found answer in 1 iteration." *)
```

Output:

[image]

For more complex cases, you may want to simplify the graph first:

[image]

---

### Under the hood

When you build the graph with `buildGraph` it will define the `VertexCoordinates`, `VertexCapacity`, `VertexWeight` and `"EdgeWeight"` + intersections for each edge under "Intersections" property.

Applying `simplify`, will:

- Remove `1-1` cases
- Limit edges connected to nodes with a capacity of 1 to a maximum of 1
- Limit `2-2` cases to the maximum 1 capacity
- For odd capacities, like nodes with capacity 3 and 2 edges, will raise the minimum edge capacity to 1
- For even capacities, like node with capacity 4 and 2 edges, will assign 2 for `"EdgeWeight"` for each edge

For finding a solution, a list of each edge min, max weight, nodes capacities, connections for each node, and edges intersections will be sent and Google OR-Tools will find combinations of edge weight that satisfy node capacity and prevent intersection. It will send a combination to Wolfram-part and it checks whether the graph with the combinations is weakly connected or not. If it's not, it will ask for the next combination, if not, the search is ended.

You could manipulate the code to give you all the answers.

For the above complex case, it took 70 iterations to find the answer and that was under `1` second (~0.5 more specifically).

I've tried other approaches to tackle this challenge, but wolfram's efficiency in graph computation is not ready to compete with OR-Tools constraint solver at least in my testing on this challenge.

---

### Bonus

One of the websites I found useful is [menneske](https://menneske.no/hashi/) which could generate Hashi puzzles with different sizes and difficulties. It could be amusing but what if we were stuck? How can we bring that puzzle in Mathematica? well here is the javascript snippet:

```javascript
result=[];
n=document.querySelectorAll('div.hashi table tr').length;
document.querySelector('div.hashi table').querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function(row,row_index){
  row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(cell,col_index){
    if(cell.innerText!==""){ 
      result.push([[col_index,n-row_index],parseInt(cell.innerText)]);
    }
  })
})

JSON.stringify(result)
```

Run the script above in the console and use `ImportString[...,"JSON"]` to parse it and use it as input to the defined functions.

Comment: @Benlzd:  Oh my goodness... what a lot of excellent work here.  Congratulations and many thanks ($+1, \checkmark$).